# Custom font reflect in dreamweaver but not view in browser

Tags: html, css, fonts

I had used a custom font in my website, its can be view in Dreamweaver design view, but not in browsers.

HTML:

```
<div id="middle"
<p class="tamilfont"> iggps; rj sdgdsg </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Tamil Bible;
    src: url(../fonts/Tamil Bible.ttf);
}
.tamilfont{
    font-family: Tamil Bible;
}
```

Preview in DW:

[image]

Preview in Browser:

[image]

What's going wrong here. please help

Thanks!

Comment: I think 'tamilfont' work in dreamweaver because dreamweaver has already install that font but in the case of browser, I think you don't have such kind of font in you browser. To make sure, open your browser, go to 'Content' tab and check that font type in Font drop down. Hope it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean it's not available when you upload it to a host? or it's not available when you try to view it in your browser on local host? If your trying to do it from another host make sure you upload the font to the same directory on the web host. If you are looking for a more friendly way i would highly suggest Google Fonts, and see if you can find the same font.

```
@font-face { font-family: //FontName; src: url('//fontUrlHere'); } 
 @font-face { font-family: //FontName; font-weight: bold; src: url('//fontUrlHere');}
```

then call upon it normally